# Name argument not found

Tags: vba, excel, solver

When I am running the below code the error "`Name argument not found`" is coming for `SetCell:="$I$3"`.

```
Sub Simple_Exponential_Smoothing()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("COV_0.2").Cells(1, 49).Value = "MAD"
    Sheets("COV_0.2").Cells(1, 50).Value = "Alpha"
    lastrow = Sheets("COV_0.2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If Sheets("COV_0.2").Cells(x, 31).Value <> "S4" Then
            Range("G" & x & ":AD" & x).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Analysis_Constant").Select
            Range("C4").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverReset"

   '***ERROR ON THE FOLLOWING LINE: `Name argument not found`
            Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverOk", SetCell:="$I$3", _
                MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$1", Engine:=3, _
                EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"

            Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", CellRef:="$G$1", _
                Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.9"
            Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverAdd", CellRef:="$G$1", _
                Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.1"
            SolverSolve True
```

Comment: **PLEASE** edit this to use Markdown formatting.  Thanks!

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: Try running with the arguments in order but without the arg descriptors.

Comment: There's probably not a file named: `Solver.xlam!SolverOk` or `Solver.xlam!SolverAdd`

Comment: Or record with a macro to check syntax. You should also have checked the reference to Solver in tools > references

Comment: To expand on @QHarr's comment: you can't pass named arguments with `Application.Run` - you can only pass by position.

Answer (score 0):

You must set a reference to the Solver addin in Tools/References:

1. Select References from the Tools menu in the Excel VBA editor window.
2. Check the "Solver" checkbox.
3. Click OK.

And then the correct Solver syntax would be:

```
SolverReset

SolverOk SetCell:="$I$3", _
    MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$1", Engine:=3, _
    EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"

SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0.9"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.1"
SolverSolve True
```

---

- Additionally I recommend not to use `Integer` for row counting because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA.
- And you might want to have a look into [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to make your code more reliable, shorter, more stable and a lot faster.